# Jenkins showing skipped artfacts/modules

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have see jenkins have a behaviour I cannot explain. It shows one module and its several artfacts as "skipped" as every other element passes the build process. The skipped artefacts were previously renamed by me so they are not part of the current commit to be built. After all they should not even be mentioned anymore.

In this context, I am facing another strange behavior: some new artefacts are skipped as well but they are well referenced within the pom.xml. So after the jenkins build new developed features are not available.

The interesting thing is: In my IDE the build is fine. Jenkins also says everthing is ok. But the result differs in what I explained.

What is this all about these skipped artefacts/modules and how to remove these obsolete modules/artefacts?

Comment: jenkins may not updating your code. delete the build workspace and try again

Comment: I am suffering from this as well. I am really looking for a nice answer, cause this is annoying.